# Route attribute with wildcard on the left

Tags: asp.net-web-api-routing, attributerouting

I want to be able to automatically match routes that may or may not have a prefix on the left of the incoming request's route.

For example, for this controller

    `[MyRoutePrefix("api/hello-world")]
    public class MyController
    {
        [Route("")]
        public IHttpActionResult Get(){ return OK(); }
    }`

I'd like the following requests to be matched up with MyController:

`http://example.com/api/hello-world`

`http://example.com/us/api/hello-world`

`http://example.com/any-word/api/hello-world`

Thanks.